# Python & Django plugins for Vim

Tags: python, django, vim, plugins

Any recommendations for specific Python and/or Django plugins for Vim?

Thanks.

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki as there is no correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/UsingVimWithDjango

Answer (score 1):

python.vim http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30